# Tag cleanup for [foxpro] and [visual-foxpro]

Tags: discussion, tags

**The Situation**

There is currently a [visual-foxpro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-foxpro) tag that should be used for anything to do with the Visual FoxPro language.

There is also a [foxpro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foxpro) tag that is being interpreted as the tag to use for Visual FoxPro questions.  I believe that this tag should be used for the FoxPro programming language (the ancestor of Visual FoxPro, since replaced in the mid 90's).

There are 661 questions using the [visual-foxpro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-foxpro) tag, 404 not using the [foxpro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foxpro) tag.

There are 586 questions using the [foxpro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foxpro) tag but...

- 257 of these questions also use the [visual-foxpro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-foxpro) tag
- 329 of these questions do not use the [visual-foxpro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-foxpro) tag

Sampling some of the [foxpro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foxpro) questions shows that the majority are wrongly tagged.  Users are commonly using only [foxpro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foxpro) or both tags to refer to Visual FoxPro questions.

A search for terms such as "foxpro", "dos", "1.0", "2.0", "2.5", "2.6", etc. shows that the number of expected questions in the [foxpro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foxpro) tag should be a lot lower (easily under 100, maybe as low as 50).

**Possible Options**

> 1. Merge [foxpro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foxpro) and [visual-foxpro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-foxpro) together, relying on the question content to explicitly state they are using FoxPro v1 to 2.6 (there are questions that do this)
> 2. Update the [foxpro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foxpro) wiki to distinguish it from [visual-foxpro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-foxpro), and review all [foxpro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foxpro), making decisions on a case by case basis
> 3. Create a new tag (e.g. [original-foxpro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/original-foxpro)), move questions that clearly state the DOS, Linux, Mac, v1, v2, v2.5 and v2.6 versions into the new tag, then merge remaining [foxpro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foxpro) into [visual-foxpro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-foxpro)

Hopefully, the results will be:

- Approx 600 questions in [visual-foxpro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-foxpro)
- Approx 50 questions in [foxpro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foxpro) (or its clearer replacement tag)
- A clearer distinction between Visual FoxPro and FoxPro questions

Answer (score 1):

I would like to propose the following (which is option 3 in the original post):

1. Create a new tag called [original-foxpro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/original-foxpro), detailing that this refers to the older v1, v2, v2.5 and v2.6 versions of FoxPro (and maybe a "DO NOT USE FOR VISUAL FOXPRO" style warning)
2. Move questions specifically referring to these older FoxPro version to the new tag
3. [foxpro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foxpro) questions are merged into [visual-foxpro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-foxpro)
4. [foxpro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foxpro) is removed for being ambiguous

Note - Cannot proceed to next step until current step completed

I think this would involve the least amount of effort, and clear up the ambiguous nature of the [foxpro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foxpro) tag.